# spring многопоточность

Tags: java, spring

выкинул из кода все лишнее:

```
@RestController
@Scope("prototype")
public class Test {

    private static List<DiOr> deliveryOrderList;
    private static List<TK> objList;
    private static ExecutorService executor;

    public Test() {
        objList = new ArrayList<TK>();
        objList.add(new Obj1());
        objList.add(new Obj2());
        // неизвестно сколько может быть ...

        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(objList.size());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    public synchronized static List<DiOr> getTest() {

        deliveryOrderList = new ArrayList<>();

        objList.stream().forEach((s) -> {
            final TK finalS = s;
            executor.submit(() -> {
                deliveryOrderList.add(finalS.get());
            });
        });

        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        return deliveryOrderList;
    }
}
```

в итоге хочу добиться, что бы при обращении к урл /test, объекты созданные в конструкторе, запускали один метод (каждый метод выполняется за разное время) в отдельном потоке кого либо пула. после завершения выполнения всех потоков пула, метод возвращал некий json (тут проблем нет).

Поскольку возвращаемый объект статичный, если убрать synchronized static - при одновременном запросе к урл более одного раза, будут возвращаться неверные данные, какой то метод отработает, какой то не успеет и тд.

Когда дописываю synchronized static (как в примере) все выполняется корректно, но как я понимаю образуется очередь на выполнение этих пулов... и при одновременном запросе в данному урл, из за очереди, значительно увеличивается время работы, для тех кто стоит в этой очереди. Для меня это критично...

Как лучше решать такую задачку?

Comment: Не совсем понятна задача, которую хотите решить. Лучше опишите как должно работать, и как уже реализовано с минимальным примером.

Comment: сейчас попробую подробнее описать

Comment: если оптимизировать метод getTest()  то можно хорошо по времени выиграть. `finalS.get()` что делает ? 
`forEach()` нужно заменить на `parallelStram().map()`

Comment: finalS.get() - по api пуляет запросы на сторонние серверы и возвращает их ответ. Спасибо за parallelStram, сейчас буду пробовать... мне скорость важна в данном случае

Comment: я бы порекомендовал deliveryOrderList сделать synchronized volatile  для добавления данных в разных потоках, и синхронизирвоать распараллельить finalS.get()

Comment: я так понимаю это не избавит от очереди? или я не понял что вы имеете ввиду... ( может в спринге есть аннотация какая нибудь волшебная, которая не знаю как выразиться, параллелит очереди, что ли... потому что иногда один пул потоков, может работать и 10 и 20 секунд. а тот кто стоит в очереди за ним, будет просто вечность ждать

Comment: зависит от того, что делает твой метод  finalS.get()

Comment: finalS.get() - выполняет запрос через HttpClient на удаленный урл, получает и распарсивает json, создает объект на основании данных из json-а и возвращает его... добавил volatile, - появилась ошибка Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@62d6fead rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6f7ce211[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 7] появляется когда делаю 2-3 запроса примерно в одно и тоже время

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите, чтобы ваш код работал быстро, то ни в коем случае нельзя синхронизировать контроллер. Таким образом вы превращаете свой сервис в однопоточный, способный обрабатывать лишь один запрос за раз.

В `spring`е,  редко приходиться явно создавать пул тредов, и это не ваш случай.
Если очень сильно хочется то можно побаловаться аннотацией `@Async`.

Из вашего вопроса, не понятно, зачем создавать разделяемое статическое поле. Вполне же можно обойтись и без него:

```
@RestController
public class Test {

   private static List<TK> objList;

   @PostConstruct
   public void setup() {
      objList = new ArrayList<TK>();
      objList.add(new Obj1());
      objList.add(new Obj2());
      // неизвестно сколько может быть ...
   }


   @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
   public List<DiQr>getTest() {

      List<DiOr> deliveryOrderList = new ArrayList<DiQr>();

      objList
            .parallelStream()
            .forEach((s) -> {
                deliveryOrderList.add(s.get());
            });

      return deliveryOrderList;
   }
}
```